# Favicon.ico Error in NextJs App Directory

Tags: next.js, icons, favicon, next.js13, ico

I have this favicon.ico file that I put on the root of `/app`, and I want to change it to another image of favicon.ico. So, I temporarily change the old favicon.ico file to favicon2.ico and change to favicon.ico after .

Now, everytime I call the `yarn dev` script, it need that favicon2.ico file.

[image]

I already tried searching on the next js app directory documentation and can't find the solution.

Right now, I just need to make that favicon2.ico file so that it want to compile but for me its a problem to have unnecessary file when I'm developing.

Did I do something wrong and can someone tell me what it is?
Or is it a bug that need to be fix?